# ¿Es "la amoladora" o "el amoladora"?

Tags: gramática, género, artículos

Para el caso de agua es "el agua" y para arroz "el arroz" entonces para [amoladora](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroesmeriladora), ¿no debería que ser "el amoladora"? Pero me suena raro, por eso pregunto.

Comment: Al usar esta palabra, por lo menos en México, conviene tener en cuenta la posible confusión con [amolar](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/amolar). En México esa máquina usualmente se denota como 'afiladora'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*El agua* lleva *el* porque, a pesar de que *agua* es palabra femenina (decimos que *está fría*), la primera sílaba es tónica y el primer fonema es /a/.  Si colocamos un adjetivo entre el artículo y el sustantivo, vuelve a ser *la*: *la cristalina agua* (pero *el agua cristalina*).

*El arroz* tiene *el* porque es masculino.

Para que aparezca obligatoriamente la aloforma *el* (que dice *la*) o facultativamente la aloforma *un* (que dice *una*), es necesario cumplir lo siguiente:

1. ser sustantivo femenino
2. aparecer el sustantivo justo después del artículo
3. comenzar el sustantivo /a/
4. acentuarse el sustantivo en la primera sílaba

Cumple con (1) el caso de *[el/la] amoladora* porque es sustantivo femenino (1).  También con (2) porque tiene el artículo seguido por el sustantivo sin otra palabra interpuesta.  Tampoco hay problema hasta (3), porque comienza con /a/.  Pero no cumple con (4) porque la primera sílaba no es la acentuada (es la cuarta: *amoladóra*).  Así que, no se dice *el amoladora*, sino siempre ***la amoladora*.**

Comment: _aloforma_, nunca había leído (ni oído) esta palabra. ¡Gran respuesta!

Comment: Interesante; sin embargo, se dice "la ama de casa" (femenino, sustantivo después del artículo, comienza sustantivo con "a" y acento en la primera sílaba)...

Comment: @euromicelli es cierto que hay excepciones como *hache*, *a*, nombres propios y alguna otra, pero yo nunca he escuchado *la ama de casa*, siempre ha sido *el ama de casa*. ¿qué dialecto hablas? Puede que haya

Comment: .... diferencias regionales que afecten la selección.

Comment: @EuroMicelli: ¿Dónde?  En Argentina siempre dije y escuché "el ama de casa".

Comment: Venezuela, pero definitivamente hay ambigüedad y duda. Preguntando al resto de la familia ha "iniciado la tercera guerra mundial", en palabras de mi hermano. Hablando de Argentina, ver también: http://m.lavoz.com.ar/blogs/ama-casa-o-ama-casa

Comment: @EuroMicelli Según el [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/?key=agua&origen=REDPD) es _el ama_.